# Textbox not displaying value after selecting from ComboBox Dropdown

Tags: c#, combobox, textbox, datasource, dropdown

so I have a `Combo Box` and I have a list made using a `KeyValuePair<int, decimal>`. I want the textbox I have selected to show the value according to the key when I select it from drop-down textbox.

Relevant code:

```
// Make a list of truck weight and MPG.
List<KeyValuePair<int, decimal>> weightMPG = new List<KeyValuePair<int, decimal>>();

private void mainForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    decimal k = 7;
    for (int i = 20000; i < 40000; i+=1000){
        weightMPG.Add(new KeyValuePair<int, decimal>(i, k));
        k -= 0.1m;
    }
    for (int i = 40000; i < 45000; i+=1000){
        weightMPG.Add(new KeyValuePair<int, decimal>(i, 5));
    }
    weightMPG.Add(new KeyValuePair<int, decimal>(46000, 4.9m));
    weightMPG.Add(new KeyValuePair<int, decimal>(47000, 4.8m));
    weightMPG.Add(new KeyValuePair<int, decimal>(48000, 4.7m));
    truckWeight2.DataSource = weightMPG;
    truckWeight2.ValueMember = "Value";
    truckWeight2.DisplayMember = "Key";
}

private void truckWeight2_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    truckMPG2.Text = truckWeight2.ValueMember;
}
```

For this code, it shows a dropdown from 20,000 to 48,000 when I click the control. However when I select one, the textbox (`truckMPG2`) doesn't update to reflect the value, rather it just always displays word "Value."

I've looked at other stack-overflow answers when making this code, so I'm not sure where I am going wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're reading the `.ValueMember` property:

```
truckMPG2.Text = truckWeight2.ValueMember;
```

Which you specifically set to a literal string:

```
truckWeight2.ValueMember = "Value";
```

It sounds like you want the `.SelectedValue` property instead:

```
truckMPG2.Text = truckWeight2.SelectedValue;
```

Or, if the type doesn't match but the value can be directly represented as a string, you might need to append `.ToString()` to the value:

```
truckMPG2.Text = truckWeight2.SelectedValue.ToString();
```

Comment: Maybe it'll clear it up, but I basically want the text-box to display the corresponding decimal number. e.g. 20,000 -> 7; 21,000->6.9 etc. I'm not sure why I set the ValueMember to Value, I was just trying out stuff from SO answers.

Comment: @Annabelle: Wait, when you set `.ValueMember` to `"Value"` does the list not display the correct values at all?  What is the `.SelectedValue` when you change a selection?  Don't just copy/paste code from Stack Overflow answers.  Specifically write statements which perform operations you want to perform.  If you're unsure what any given statement does, look up the documentation and experiment with it in your debugger to see what it does.

Comment: The list itself displays the correct members(keys). However the textbox where I want the value (e.g. the 7, 6.9..etc) simply displays the word "Value." also when using `.SelectedValue;` I simply get a casting error.

Comment: @Annabelle: And what is the error?  What is the type of `.SelectedValue`?  What value does it hold?  Can you simply put `.ToString()` on the end of it?  Be *specific* about the problem you're seeing.

Comment: Yes, I can. Thank you. Not sure why that didn't occur to me.